# How to illustrate array lists into sequence diagram?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, uml, sequence-diagram

```
public boolean uploadResult(Lecturer lecturer, Student student, String result) throws NullPointerException {
    Schedule currentSchedule = scheduleService.findCurrentSchedule();
    if (currentSchedule.getWeek() != 12) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot upload result until the end of the semester.");
    }
    Student stu = studentService.findOne(student);
    List<Enrolment> enrolments = stu.getPerformance();
    Enrolment enrolment = null;
    for (Enrolment e : enrolments) {
        CourseOffering offering = e.getOffering();
        if (offering.getLecturer().equals(lecturer) && offering.getSchedule().equals(currentSchedule)) {
            enrolment = e;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (enrolment == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("There is no such student in the lecturer's course");
    }
    enrolment.setResult(result);
    studentService.save(student);
    return true;
}
```

I'm trying to understand the above code in order to illustrate it in a sequence diagram, but I'm having some trouble understanding some of it, particularly this part:

```
List<Enrolment> enrolments = stu.getPerformance();
    Enrolment enrolment = null;
    for (Enrolment e : enrolments) {
        CourseOffering offering = e.getOffering();
        if (offering.getLecturer().equals(lecturer) && 
offering.getSchedule().equals(currentSchedule)) {
            enrolment = e;
            break;
```

[My current sequence diagram in progress(LINK)](https://www.lucidchart.com/invitations/accept/2881f67d-e0d3-4d1a-9045-875f23f6b424)

[image: My current sequence diagram in progress]

Comment: And what exactly is it that you don't understand. An array is a structure, but a SD is about behavior.

Comment: You’re missing a few objects. E.g. getPerformance() is on the object ‘stu’ (type Student), getOffering() is on object ‘e’ (type Enrolment) and you have an object ‘offering’ (type CourseOffering against which getLecturer() and getSchedule() are called, not getOffering() as per your diagram — also we know the name of that CourseOffering object (offering) so the name doesn’t need to be empty (I.e. :CourseOffering => offering:CourseOffering)). The logic is all in the code, you just need to follow it in the diagram.